# TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function - Loop through firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling to understand why my function is failing when trying to loop through a snapshot from Firebase Realtime Database.

The function should read through each 'Topic', from within each 'Topic' there is an 'Articles' field which has approximately 10 articles associated with it. The function reads each article URL and scrapes the URL for the largest image on the article website.
It should then add a new field 'imageURL' to each 'Article'.

When deployed I receive the following:

> TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function

**scraper.js**

```
exports.imageScraper = functions.database.ref("searchTrends/google")
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
  functions.logger.error(snapshot);
  snapshot.forEach(function(trendSnapshot) {
    // TrendSnapshot - Key is topic Num
    // Value is topic details with list of articles
    const topicNum = trendSnapshot.key;
    trendSnapshot.forEach(function(innerChild) {
      if (innerChild.key == "articles") {
        innerChild.forEach(function(articleData) {
          const articleNum = articleData.key;
          const myUrl = articleData.child("url").val();
          // console.log(myUrl);

          const options = {
            url: myUrl,
          };
          // console.log(options);

          ogs(options, (error, results, response) => {
            if (typeof results.ogImage === "undefined") {
              console.log("no Image");
            } else {
              if (results.ogImage.url === undefined) {
                return "done";
              }
              console.log(articleNum);
              const DBRef = admin.database().ref("searchTrends/google/" +
              topicNum + "/articles/" + articleNum);
              DBRef.update({imageURL: results.ogImage.url});
            }
          });
        });
        return "done";
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
      return null;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `snapshot` does not have a method called `forEach`.  It is a not a DataSnapshot object as you are expecting.  It is a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.change) object, specifically `Change<DataSnapshot>`  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions#handle_event_data):

> For onWrite or onUpdate events, the first parameter is a Change object that contains two snapshots that represent the data state before and after the triggering event.

Also refer to the API documentation for [onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.database.refbuilder#databaserefbuilderonupdate).